# Horizontal scrolling issue in shiny R

Tags: r, scroll, shiny, horizontal-scrolling, dt

I am in new shiny R and I'm having an issue with the horizontal scrolling. Here is my code.

```
output$sbirx.view <- DT::renderDataTable(
{
  dataset.filter()
}, options = list(
                  searching = TRUE,
                  autoWidth=TRUE,
                  paging=FALSE,
                  scrollX=TRUE,
                  scrollY="500px",
                  scrollCollapse = TRUE,
                  fixedHeader=TRUE,
                  fixedColumns=list(leftColumns = 2, rightColumns = 0, 
                                    heightMatch = 'none')
                ),
            rownames=FALSE,
            class = 'cell-border stripe',
            extensions = c('FixedColumns',"FixedHeader")
```

)

The data has 79 columns and I have option on how many columns I want to display. The first 2 leftcolumns(DISEASE and PRODUCT) should be fixed and if you're only showing 3 columns, the table looks like this. But if I choose sveral columns that would fit the screen it has no problem.

Disease   PRODUCT     Disease    PRODUCT    2010-11
Disease1  Product1    Disease1   Product1   25,000
Disease1  Product2    Disease1   Product2   15,000
Disease1  Product3    Disease1   Product3   5,000

Is there a way to fix this using any options?

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like it was as simple as correcting your declarations of options and specifying the missing `Scroller` extension:

```
library("shiny")
library("DT")

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    dataTableOutput("data")
  )
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$data <- renderDataTable({
    datatable(cbind(iris, iris, iris, iris), 
              extensions = c("FixedColumns", "FixedHeader", "Scroller"), 
              options = list(
                # dom = 't',
                # deferRender = TRUE,
                searching = TRUE,
                autoWidth = TRUE,
                # scrollCollapse = TRUE,
                rownames = FALSE,
                scroller = TRUE,
                scrollX = TRUE,
                scrollY = "500px",
                fixedHeader = TRUE,
                class = 'cell-border stripe',
                fixedColumns = list(
                  leftColumns = 3,
                  heightMatch = 'none'
                  )
                )
              )
  })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Hello mlegge. Thank you for your time. I've ran your code and it only shows 9 rows on my end. When I scroll it down, there are no more rows to display. However if play the scroll arrow up and down. It's displaying the rest of the rows. I applied your code on my end. It did solve the issue that I was having however it is only display certain number of rows. Although it says at the bottom that there were more than the number of entries that has to be displayed.

Comment: Just disable the scroll collapse (see edit) and you should have the functionality you desire

Comment: Appreciate it very much! Your help means a lot to me since I am new to R and Shiny.  Have a great day!

Comment: No problem, if the solution solves your problem please click the check mark right under the upvote/downvote buttons. I see that you haven't accepted answers to your other questions -- if you want people to keep answering your questions it would be a good idea to accept solutions on those too.

Comment: I'm sorry where would I find this button so I could vote. Thanks

Comment: Please don't worry about it. I think I got. it.